# karate api : Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: karate

When i am tring to upload a image using karate framework i am getting exception as

```
{
    "message":"Required request part 'file' is not present", 
    "code":500,
    "className":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException"
}
```

Karate code

```
Scenario: Adding image  
Given path Endpoints.upload_file  
And multipart file myFile = { read: 'karate-logo.jpg', filename: karate-logo.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpg' }  

And multipart field message = 'image test'  
When method post
```

API works fine when i try to hit using postman.
Just need to send file in body section with form data key as 'file' and value as the image to upload.

Answer (score 1):

The "key" here `myFile` is the name of the uploaded field. Looks like your server is expecting `file`.  Please rename `myFile` to `file` and it should work.